# Tag found but class not visible Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've spent over 4 hours and counting trying to get an element that's visible on the web page but won't pull when I try using Selenium to scrape it. I even tried to copy direct xpath to element but still does not work. Inspecting the page on my browser shows the structure to be like this.

```
<div class="flex-deprecated flex-items-xs-center">
  <div>...<div>
  <div style="position:relative">
    <div class="row flex-xs-nowrap no-margin form-left form-box-container ">
      <div class="form-box flex-xs-no-grow cursor-pointer ">
        <svg class="margin-center">
          <rect class="form-in-shape"></rect>
          <text class="form-win-text">TEXT</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="form-box flex-xs-no-grow cursor-pointer ">...</div>
      <div class="form-box flex-xs-no-grow cursor-pointer ">...</div>
      <div class="form-box flex-xs-no-grow cursor-pointer ">...</div>
      <div class="form-box flex-xs-no-grow cursor-pointer ">...</div>
      <div class="row flex-items-xs-middle form-arrow-line no-margin left">...</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

TEXT is what I'm scraping for, I was able to locate upto all the 5 `div` tags with `class="form-box flex-xs-no-grow cursor-pointer "`, but it won't find the `svg` tag or the `text` tag, when I try using the direct xpath, it finds up to the `text` tag but returns empty string with I try to get the text within the tag.
Here is my code as I am currently out of ideas on how to approach this.

```
z = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='sub-container head-to-head']/div[3]/div/div[@class='panel margin-bottom ']/div/div[@class='row']")
        
        z1 = z.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='col-xs-6']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-7 flex-deprecated flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center']/div/div[@class='visible-md-up hidden-xs-up']/div/div[@class='row']/div/div/div[2]/div[@class='row flex-xs-nowrap no-margin form-left form-box-container ']")
        z2 = z1.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='form-box flex-xs-no-grow cursor-pointer ']")
        
        try:
            for i_ in range(0, 5):
                ztemp1 = z2[i_].find_element_by_class_name("margin-center")
                wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "form-with-text")))
                #ztemp = ztemp1.find_elements_by_class_name("form-with-text")
                ztemp =ztemp1.find_element_by_tag_name("text")
                #print("TESTIN>>> {}".format(len(ztemp)))
                print("SKKKKKK>>>>> {}".format(ztemp.text))
                z3 = z2[i_].find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
                
                print('good here {}'.format(len(z3)))
                
        except(NoSuchElementException):
            print('Tag or Class not found')
```

When I try to find the `text` tag by class name, it does not find it, but it finds it when I search by tag name but it's an empty string. Here's the link to the site I'm using [Source Site][1]

Any help and tip will be highly appreciated.
[1]: https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/betking/en/1/season/83706/headtohead/17/42/match/27751100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a svg element. You can locate like this :

```
//*[name()='svg' and @class='margin-center']//*[name()='text']
```

this is giving me 66 web elements.

you can loop through it like below :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/betking/en/1/season/83706/headtohead/17/42/match/27751100")

for txt in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @class='margin-center']//*[name()='text']"):
  print(txt.text)
```

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, The svg element is of two separate categories, one for home and one for away, when you open the site it will show them like that, I'm supposed to scrape them separately like that, but if I get the whole svg in the page then I won't be able to tell which is which.

Comment: yes you can have two list with two find_elements in that case, Do you need help for that as well ?

Comment: I should be able to figure that out, thanks.

Comment: just remember, this is the way to find svg tag, `//*[name()='svg']  ` you can put and @class or any other attribute to match the nodes you want to scrape.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/betking/en/1/season/83706/headtohead/17/42/match/27751100")
time.sleep(5)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'col-sm-5')]//div[contains(@class,'hidden-md-up')]")
for ele in elements:
    datalist = []
    data = ele.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'cursor-pointer')]")
    for d in data:
        datalist.append(d.get_attribute("innerText"))
    print(datalist)
```

Output:

```
['W', 'L', 'L', 'W', 'W']
['L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'D']
```